# Unexpected Output using Struct Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, output

So I have a struct, and within that struct I have a array of chars that is meant to store a phone number. Format being xxxxxxxxxx (with x being a digit from 0-9). Then, I'm running a for loop to format the display of those ten digits while printing.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 
 
void clear(void);
 
struct Student {
    int idNumber;
    char firstName[25];
    char lastName[25];
    char cellNumber[15];
    char grade, grade2;
    char semester[11], semester2[11];
    char course[10], course2[10];
};
 
int main() {
 
    struct Student studentArr[2];
 
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
 
        printf("For student %d...\n", x+1);
        printf("Enter student number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &studentArr[x].idNumber);
        printf("%d", studentArr[x].idNumber);
        printf("Enter student's first name: \n");
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].firstName);
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].firstName);
        printf("Enter student's last name: \n");
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].lastName);
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].lastName);
        printf("Enter student's cell number: \n");
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].cellNumber);
        printf("%c", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[1]);
        printf("(");
        //print("%s", studentArr[x].cellNumber);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("%s", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[i]);}
        printf(")");
        for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++){
            printf("%s", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[i]);}
        printf("-");
        for(int i = 6; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%s", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[i]);}
        printf("Enter course %d: \n", x+1);
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].course);
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].course);
        printf("Enter semster for course %d: \n", x+1);
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].semester);
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].semester);
        printf("Enter letter grade for course %d: \n", x+1);
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].grade);
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].grade);
        clear();
       
    }
 
}
 
void clear(void) {
 
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Here is the output:
[image: Output]

As you can see, the output for the phone number is completely messed up, also I'm ending up with a segmentation fault.

EDIT: Switched the %s to %c and now am getting this output and not prompt for user entry:
[Letters instead of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNLY.png)

Comment: To print a single character you use `printf("%c", studentArr[x].cellNumber[i]);`, and to read a grade letter use `scanf("%c", &studentArr[x].grade);`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Also, the `cellNumber[1]` there is out of place, so I ignored commenting on that line - it probably should be deleted?

Comment: @KenY-N You're correct, that line was for testing and I forgot to comment it out / delete the line.

I tried what you said, but now it skips  the user prompt when run and prints out (FGH) IJK-LMNO

Comment: [cellNumber demo](http://ideone.com/ImyC5B)

Comment: Please copy-paste actual code and output, instead of images. Not everyone can see images.

Comment: @NickM Please see the second part of my comment - use `"%c"` for characters.

Comment: @KenY-N Sorry, wasn't clear. I did what you second comment said and switched %s for %c. Now instead of a large amount of numbers, I'm getting letters. I edited original post with image.

Comment: `scanf("%s", studentArr[x].grade);
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].grade);` --> `scanf(" %c", &studentArr[x].grade); printf("%c\n", studentArr[x].grade);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for this. I switched out my 3 for loops for what you had, and it works perfectly.

Still have the segmentation fault issue, though.

Comment: try previous my comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure your compiler warnings are on. If you didn't get warnings, then you should ensure you're using a good compiler like Clang.

When I compiled your code, I got these errors:

```
$cc phone.c -o phone
phone.c:34:22: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
        printf("%c", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[1]);
                ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                %s
phone.c:52:21: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%s", studentArr[x].grade);
               ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
phone.c:53:22: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
        printf("%s", studentArr[x].grade);
                ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                %c
3 warnings generated.
```

These clue you in to what mistakes you *may* have made.

In this case, you got a little confused between characters and strings, along with some other issues.

1. Fixing your character/string issues:

   You made the error of passing a pointer to a character where you  should've just passed the char itself. To fix this, you should delete the ampersand, changing this:

   ```
   printf("%c", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[i]);
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   printf("%c", studentArr[x].cellNumber[i]);
   ```

   for each of your three lines.
2. You also probably want to print a '1' first, not the index 1 of the phone string (otherwise input `5555555555` outputs `5(555)555-5555`).

   So, change this:

   ```
   printf("%c", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[1]);
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   printf("%c", '1');    // or printf("1");
   ```

   After you do #1 and #2, you will get output like this:

   ```
   gregEnter student's last name: 
   schmit
   schmitEnter student's cell number: 
   6306089561
   1(630)608-9561Enter course 1:
   ```
3. There are still errors in your code. From here, you should compile and inspect warnings, and then search for the errors you get, as they are well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm sorry for not following posting guidelines here, I'll make sure to do so for my next post! Thanks for the advice, between what you posted and what another user posted I got my code working. Much appreciated, sir !

Comment: Not a problem. Also, feel free to mark answers as accepted if the solution helped you so others know this question has an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You are printing cell number using &. Do not use & to print value at address. & Is used to print address only.

Comment: No, it may also be used to print strings.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Your grade is char type, why are u using ℅s to take input. Use ℅c. This is an issue of segfault

Comment: @SumitGemini Thanks for the comment. Yes, I have switched to %c instead of %s. Now I am getting letters for output instead of numbers, also the prompt is being bypassed. See OP for edited image.

Comment: @KenY-N is it you downvote my answer and why?
your cellNumber is array of character "char cellNumber[10]".

now your are getting input from user.
  scanf("%s", studentArr[x].cellNumber);

and trying to read data from address? how it could be possiable?
        printf("%c", &studentArr[x].cellNumber[1]);

you should use  printf("%c", studentArr[x].cellNumber[1]); to print character.

For your knowledge 

char s[11]
Here s is &s[0] and since s is already an address.